# Cyan and Aqua why are there 2 names for the same colour?

Tags: winforms, colors

I was recently designing a Winforms application and colleague mentioned to me to ensure certain controls had a `BackColor` of `Cyan`.

I had chosen `Aqua` as this was the colour which best matched what I had seen previously used, when I switched my controls to `Cyan` I did not notice any difference

When I did a quick search I found this MSDN article/documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx which describes the ARGB values as: -

```
Cyan     |     Gets the system-defined color that has an ARGB value of #FF00FFFF.   
Aqua     |     Gets the system-defined color that has an ARGB value of #FF00FFFF.
```

Can someone explain why there are 2 values for the same colour?

Comment: Can you explain why the -1? I am just interested if anyone knows the reason why...

Comment: Probabbly because your question is really hard on the edge to Off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) color names match the Microsoft .NET Framework version 1.0, Windows Forms, and Microsoft Internet Explorer color names. This representation is based on UNIX X11 named color values.

So, basically, the answer is that it's based on the Unix X11 names. You can find more info at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names). The X11 color names are based on W3C  standard color sets, and there are various other equivalents too like Magenta and Fuschia.

Does this matter to you? Hmmm not really except maybe in Silverlight. The defined color set is very minimized and in this case you would *have* to use Cyan over Aqua because Aqua doesn't exist in Silverlight's Color class.